# Why doesn't the 1st plural (nous) form of passé simple end in -ons?

Tags: étymologie, passé-simple

I noticed that the *nous* form of verbs always ends in *-ons*. For example, *nous allons/allions/irons/allions/allassions/irions*. However, the passé simple tense of verbs seems to always end in *-mes* (with the previous letter being a vowel with a circumflex).

Why is there this inconsistency? Is it because passé simple is a literary tense and "hasn't evolved" for some time? At least to me, it looks closer to Latin *-mus* than the other ending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The development of the ending *-ons* seems to be pretty unclear. *[Grammaticalization: Studies in Latin and Romance Morphosyntax](https://books.google.com/books?id=L4hslm-UMrkC&pg=PA52),* by Jürgen Klausenburger (2002), describes it as "one of the most puzzling questions of Romance historical linguistics" (p. 51).

Klausenburger says that Corbett (1969) actually suggested that *-ons* may have come to be established in the present tense as a way of avoiding homophony with the perfect form derived from Latin *-āvimus,* which apparently is thought to have developed a geminate (/mm/, I guess, as in Italian *cantammo*) to "compensate" for the loss of *-vi-,* but then underwent degemination to produce a form with /m/ (p. 52).

Apparently, the imperfect and conditional 1plr forms used to end in  *-iens* in Old French.